# Merge 2 cell at sql server

Tags: sql-server

I use sql server. i want to merge two tables. 
Say i have 2 table

table 1

```
id | item_id | item_name | load_qty
1   1          YRD         3
2   1          YRD         4
3   2          SS          2
4   2          SS          3
5   3          SS          7
```

table 2

```
id | item_id | delivery_arrive               | recevie_qty
1    1         2019-08-22 11:38:36.6820000     2
2    1         2019-08-23 11:38:36.6820000     3
3    2         2019-08-22 11:38:36.6820000     1
```

my expected result is

```
id | item_id | item_name | load_qty | delivery_arrive             |recevie_qty
1   1          YRD         3          2019-08-22 11:38:36.6820000  2             
2   1          YRD         4          2019-08-23 11:38:36.6820000  3
3   2          SS          2          2019-08-22 11:38:36.6820000  1
4   2          SS          3          
5   3          SS          7
```

Comment: left join by id

Comment: Please complete your entry with the current state of your solution approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.delivery_arrive, t2.recevie_qty
  FROM table1 as t1 
       LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```